# Swagger Open API Custom header

Tags: swagger

I am facing fellow two problems related to Swagger open API

1. I am not able to pass custom header through swagger open API while calling my API, please suggest how can we pass custom header, through swagger open API.
2. When I added POI dependency on my project's pom.xml, it stopped working through swagger open API, however, it is working with the postman, please suggest what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [Describing Parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#header-parameters):

> An API call may require that custom headers be sent with an HTTP request. OpenAPI lets you define custom request headers as `in: header` parameters. For example, suppose, a call to `GET /ping` requires the `X-Request-ID` header:
>
> ```
> GET /ping HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> X-Request-ID: 77e1c83b-7bb0-437b-bc50-a7a58e5660ac
> ```
>
> Using OpenAPI 3.0, you would define this operation as follows:
>
> ```
> paths:
>   /ping:
>     get:
>       summary: Checks if the server is alive
>       parameters:
>         - in: header
>           name: X-Request-ID
>           schema:
>             type: string
>             format: uuid
>           required: true
> ```